# Dynamically sizing DIV to fit a space that is resized on different screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to size a layout so that the image is 100% of the screen width. I got that part, but when I try to put a div so that it fits in the box in the image, I can't seem to get it be reliable for different sizes of the screen. Is there a way to ensure that my div will sit inside my box? I've attached the relevant part of my code for reference. I'm testing on two different size screens (a smaller chromebook, and a 17" Toshiba). I'm just learning responsive web-design so I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Thank you!

```
<div id="banner">
  <img src="http://grouptheory.sammiirose.com/group%20theory%20header%202.png" width="100">
</div>
<div id="stuff">
  Test words in here
</div>
<style type="text/css">
  #banner{ top: 0%; width:100%;}
  #stuff { position: absolute; height: 70%; top: 25%; left: 1%; width: 72%;
           border: 1px solid black; overflow: auto; color: #000000; 
           text-align: center;}
</style>
```

Comment: Do you want to fit the image in banner div with "full width"(of div size) or inside the stuff div?

Comment: In the banner I have a small box that I want the stuff div to fit into

Comment: try changing in <img> tag make width='100%'.

Comment: I had tried that, but I couldn't get the div stuff to line up across all screens

Comment: if possible add image or wireframe what you exactly want because the question you provided doesn't explain your problem properly.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question well, but I think you need this.

```
    <div id="stuff">
      <div id="banner">
          <img src="http://grouptheory.sammiirose.com/group%20theory%20header%202.png">
        </div>
      Test words in here
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
      #banner img{ width:100%;}
      #stuff { position: absolute; height: 70%; top: 25%; left: 1%; width: 72%;
               border: 1px solid black; color: #000000; 
               text-align: center;}
    </style>
```